# Playing video as a splashsceen of a windows phone 8 hybrid application

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst

How can I play an MP4 video as a splash screen on a hybrid windows phone 8 / 8.1 app (IBM MobileFirst 6.3) instead of the default jpg splash screen?

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem to be feasible to replace the splash image with a video file, as according to MSDN documentation, only images are applicable.

See the following:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465338.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769511%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I don't think its possible.

File name format:

SplashScreenImage.<screen-WVGA>.jpg, 
SplashScreenImage.<screen-WVGA>.png

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769511%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

The file name and extension is fixed. You can specify resolution as a part of the image name and the OS will automatically pick it.